# Code prints time in millisec

Tags: java

This is my code and I am getting a huge output. My code should output the time in milliseconds. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int num = rand.nextInt(100); 
static long linear = System.currentTimeMillis();
//Linear Search in Unsorted array
private static int linearSearch(int list[],int key)
{

//finds an element in a list
   for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
   {
       //if element is found, element is then returned
       if(list[i]==key)
           return i;
   }
   //if element is not found, -1 is returned
   return -1;
}
System.out.println("Linear Search Time: " + linear);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your expectation is but you should take the `currentTimeMillis` after the search again and calculate the difference between the two.

Comment: That is not valid Java code. You can't have a `println()` statement outside of a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some code that will run, and print out the time it took for your function to run. The problem you are having is that you are asking for the system time, which is some massive number, because it is how long the computer has been running. To get the time your function took to run we simply ask for the time before we run let's call in t1. Then we run the function. After then function has completed running we ask for the time again let's call it t2. Then we take t2 - t1 this difference is the time it took your function to run, and the time for the calculation to be performed (minimal). Also note that in my example the time outputted will be zero, as the array is so small, and the calculation is so fast.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

Random rand = new Random(); //stays same
int num = rand.nextInt(100); //stays same
static long linear = 0;//more optimal to move where initial time is set (t1)

//main where things are run ;)
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //could be placed outside in the class
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};//some array of numbers
    int key = 5; //a key 

    linear = System.currentTimeMillis();//t1 set
    linearSearch(array, 5);//calling of your search function
    linear = System.currentTimeMillis() - linear; //obtaining the difference between the time, and t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    //the function started and when it finished
    System.out.println("Linear Search Time: " + linear);//printing out the difference, which is the time taken
    //also note that the number will likely be zero, as this function will run extremely fast for most arrays.

}

//your function
//Linear Search in Unsorted array
private static int linearSearch(int list[],int key)
{

//finds an element in a list
   for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
   {
       //if element is found, element is then returned
       if(list[i]==key)
           return i;
   }
   //if element is not found, -1 is returned
   return -1;
}

}
```

Comment: No problem, I remember having a similar problem some time ago. It is always the little things that cause problems it seems

Comment: That is true. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are trying to find how long it takes to find given key on a list using linearSearch function. Best way is to store the just before calling the function and just after returning from it, then get the difference to see time it took. Unless you have like pretty big list this might return 0ms just like in below example since computers are too fast. You could make a while loop and create huge array to see some values.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class HelloWorld{
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int num = rand.nextInt(100); 
    static long linear = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Linear Search in Unsorted array
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Linear Search Time: " + linear);

        int[] list = {1 ,3 ,4,5,6,7};
        int key = 7;
        long start_linear = System.currentTimeMillis();
        linearSearch(list,key);
        long end_linear = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("linearSearch took: " + (end_linear - start_linear) + "ms" );
     }
    private static int linearSearch(int list[],int key)
    {

    //finds an element in a list
       for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
       {
           //if element is found, element is then returned
           if(list[i]==key)
               return i;
       }
       //if element is not found, -1 is returned
       return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The output I am receiving is "1466825981421" in my code. I need it in milliseconds.

Comment: @D.Nik It is in milliseconds. Actually its giving you number of milliseconds passed since 1970 January 01. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time . You can use an online tool like http://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert that 1466825981421 to readable date

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference between time taken before and after the execution of the method 
`linearSearch(int list[],int key)`

Write the last line like this

```
System.out.println("Linear Search Time: " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - linear));
```

Comment: This is what I had on my code before, but I was only getting 0 and 1. Was that correct or should I probably be getting a decimal?

Comment: @D.Nik Not surprising. How slow do you think the linear search is? You need to measure in nano seconds go get any measurable value.

Answer (score 0):

currentTimeMillis() returns the number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

All you did was print the current time. After your search finishes, take the current time again and subtract what you got from .currentTimeMillis() the first time.

```
static long linearFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Linear Search Time: " + (linearFinish - linear));
```